# Is there a way to configure the screen percentage of 'toggleEditorWidths' in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When a hotkey is assigned to `workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths` and to `workbench.action.focus[left,right,above,below]Group` I can navigate groups easily with automatic resizing. The screen percentage of the focused group is too high, however.

[image]

Is there a way to configure the percentage of the focused pane?
i.e. currently, I'd say it takes up ~90% and I'd like it to take up 55-65% so the other groups are still semi-readable. I'm trying to mimic the behavior of an Atom plugin I used a long time ago called "HeyPane" and I haven't been able to find any plugins with this behaviour

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any built-in way to change that editor width when invoking the command `workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths` but you can produce the same result with a macro.  Using a macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "alt+o",                 // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths",

            // as many as these as looks good to you
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth"
        ]
    }
}
```

This first toggles the editor widths (which goes too far for you) and then decreases by about 10% for each `workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth`.  Just add as many of those commands as you want into the keybinding.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes it a bit more cumbersome than it's worth, since the resize is no longer automatic, but I appreciate it